# Testing Rails 3 respond_with with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I recently changed my controller code from:

```
  def create
    @checklist_item = @checklist.items.build(params[:checklist_item])
    if @checklist_item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created checklist item."
      redirect_to checklist_item_url(@checklist, @checklist_item)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

to

```
  respond_to :html, :json
  def create
    @checklist_item = @checklist.items.build(params[:checklist_item])
    if @checklist_item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created checklist item."
    end
    respond_with @checklist_item
  end
```

But my spec that worked fine with my previous controller code is failing:

```
  it "create action should render new template when model is invalid" do
    checklist_item.stub(:valid? => false)
    checklist.stub_chain(:items, :build => checklist_item)
    post :create, :checklist_id => checklist.id
    response.should render_template(:new)
  end
```

With the error:

```
1) Checklists::ItemsController create action should render new template when model is invalid
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template(:new)
     MiniTest::Assertion:
       Expected block to return true value.
```

I'm not sure how to change the spec. Everything still functions the same when I test it in the browser (its renders new).

Comment: weird it doesn't render show. You're sure it renders new?

Comment: The goal is to render :new because the model is invalid. The other test where it passes a valid model works fine and redirects to show with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty funny, just tried and indeed the `response` doesn't contain much.

It's a mere status 302. Test: `response.status.should eq 302`

With a body like:

`"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"new_url">redirected</a>.</body></html>"`

which is easily testable too.

I'll dig a little further.

---

Edit:

Even with `render_views`, `response` remains a mere redirect.

You could also check `response.header` which looks like:

```
{"Location"=>"http://test.host/users", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
```

Comment: could it be authentication is redirecting you to login page?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that responds_with checks `.errors.empty?` as opposed to `valid?` (I suppose it doesn't want to unnecessarily re-run validations). So stub out `.errors` I guess.